Do I understand correctly how to perform sequential binary partition?
I’m dealing with geochemical data. Let’s say I have the results of chemical analysis of a mineral with elements: A, B, C, X, Y, Z.  X, Y and Z are elements belonging to the same group (let’s say they’re rare earth elements), but A, B, C are not. Below I described my understanding of how it works.
It would be convenient in the first step to divide my composition into two groups: [A, B, C] and [X, Y, Z] (as it makes sense in geology to separate rare earths from the rest of elements). As I understand, I’m coding the elements as 1 and -1, like:




A
B
C
X
Y
Z




S1
1
1
1
-1
-1
-1



However, let’s assume, that besides that, all the elements have nothing more in common with one another. Therefore, performing further steps to partition my data, I’m dividing the other elements into arbitrary groups. Therefore, I could for example perform partition within XYZ group into [X] and [Y, Z] and the second step could then look like this:




A
B
C
X
Y
Z




S2
0
0
0
1
-1
-1



Then, I could apply the same reasoning to divide rest of XYZ group and ABC group and I will get something like this:




A
B
C
X
Y
Z




S1
1
1
1
-1
-1
-1


S2
0
0
0
1
-1
-1


S3
0
0
0
0
1
-1


S4
1
1
-1
0
0
0


S5
0
1
-1
0
0
0



So, am I right about that? I also understand that each time I’m analysing separate datasets, I can do the SBP from scratch for the particular dataset to make interpretation of isometric logratios more convenient – am I right about that as well?
